# Compile Linux Application for Windows

Tags: cross-compilation, cygwin, mingw

I want to use a Linux Application under Windows. It is my understanding that the application is Linux only and to use it in Windows I have to compile the application from the source using Cygwin or MinGW.

My question is which to use: Cygwin or MinGW?

Should i setup Cygwin or MinGW in Windows and then compile the Linux Application there?

Should i setup Cygwin or MinGW in Linux and then compile the Linux Application there?

Any guide/tutorial?

Comment: What features does the application use (e.g. command line or GUI, does it use unix-y features such as interprocess communication or permissions intensively)? Depending on the answer, this can go from trivial to extremely complicated.

Comment: It is a command-line application. No IPC or Permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Cygwin aims to maximise POSIX and Linux source compatibility, whereas MinGW provides a GNU toolchain for building native Windows application. Hopefully this means that your Linux application requires no or only minor changes to build on Cygwin, whereas porting code using POSIX/Linux-specific APIs to native Windows can be a major effort. However, if you can make it work with MinGW, that saves you the dependency on the Cygwin DLL.

Building with a cross-compile environment on Linux tends to be faster, but also more difficult, especially with regards to libraries that applications may depend on. And obviously you'll need to test on Windows anyway.

Comment: Setting up CygWin on Windows...

Answer (score 0):

Setup your cygwin environment on windows, then compile there.

Comment: what about setup the environment in Linux, and then compile there?

Comment: @MA1 Cygwin is a system that provides a unix like environment on top of Windows. Cygwin on top of linux would be a meaningless combination! Your application needs to be compiled in and for the environment it will run under, so it needs to be compiled in cygwin on windows since that is what you want to end up with in the end.

Comment: @MA1 Yes, you can cross-compile Windows executables on Linux. There are many tutorials covering this, this one for example: http://www.blogcompiler.com/2010/07/11/compile-for-windows-on-linux/

Comment: @Caleb The application definitely doesn't need to be compiled in the environment it is built for. Or do you think that embedded chips actually have to capable of running a compiler?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: I was simplifying for the sake of a guy who clearly doesn't understand the pieces. Of course cross-compiling is an option, but that is more complicated to understand and @MA1 hasn't put together the first pieces of the puzzle yet. If he says his software needs to be compiled, the process of getting dependencies setup to compile there will also leave a working running environment.

Comment: @Caleb Then please don't say that it isn't possible, say that it is possible, but hard to set up.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be I never said it was impossible, I said the application needs to be compiled in the environment it will run under and this is true. In the case of cross compiling, you have to set up extensive parts of the target inside the host so that the compile happens against the architecture and libraries (including version numbers) of the target instead of those on the host. In essence the compile happens in the *mock*-target environment.

Comment: @Caleb Quote: "Your application needs to be compiled in and for the environment it will run under"

Comment: @Caleb; @Let_Me_Be;                                             Great Great Thanks.....Setting up CygWin on Windows...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can work without both.

Windows (from Windows 7) claims to be fully POSIX compliant. Unfortunately as many other important features, this is only available for Enterprise and Ultimate editions.

For earlier versions of Window there are [Windows Services for UNIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Services_for_UNIX).

Comment: Even on Windows 7 Enterprise and Ultimate, the "Subsystem for Unix Applications" (aka Interix) is an optional component. Furthermore, it runs in its own subsystem directly on the NT kernel rather than within the Windows subsystem, so the result of building for Interix isn't a Windows program as such.

Comment: @ak2 Are you sure? What I read is that the SDK and utilities have to be downloaded separately, but you shouldn't need that for running the programs.

Comment: No, I'm not sure actually. For all I know the core parts of Interix could be installed by default.